# getting controller string value to another controller

Tags: javafx, controller, fxmlloader

I am having trouble understanding what to do in order to get a string value to another controller. I've searched other questions and cannot apply a solution as  some answers seem to be quite confusing to me.
I want a combo box value found in one controller to transfer over to a text field in another controller.
I made attempts to create objects from the controller class to set the text value but it fails.

here is the code in one of the controller classes (the other controller just has the variable names):

```
String name_val = item.getValue().toString(); //controller1 item value
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("contoller2.fxml"));
Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

//set value to a textfield in controller2.fxml


Stage stage_completed = new Stage();

stage_completed.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
stage_completed.show();
```

appreciate any help!

thanks!

Comment: "It fails"... How? What actually happens? Can you show the code you are calling to "set the value to a textfield" (which presumably involves calling a method on the controller for the FXML you just loaded), and post the corresponding method from that controller?

Comment: hey @James_D, so if I create an object out of the class (between the parent root1 and stage statement) and set the property value it fails such as:      
             CompleteformController c = new CompleteformController();
             c.complete_title.setText(name_val);

there is no other method in the other controller. It just holds the textfield name I am trying to control. Do I need to add something there?

Comment: But if you create your own instance, that instance is not the controller (it is a different instance of the class). You need to get the controller from the FXML loader. Again, post the code you are trying to use in the question.

Comment: you are right boss. this did the trick:

CompleteformController myControllerHandle = fxmlLoader.getController();  
           myControllerHandle.complete_title.setText(name_val);

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
String name_val = item.getValue().toString(); //controller1 item value
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("contoller2.fxml"));
Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();

//solution start
CompleteformController myControllerHandle = fxmlLoader.getController();  
           myControllerHandle.complete_title.setText(name_val);
//solution end

Stage stage_completed = new Stage();

stage_completed.setScene(new Scene(root1));  
stage_completed.show();
```